# Symfony2 Form generation collection

Tags: forms, symfony, formcollection

I've started my learning of Symfony 2 a few days ago and I have a problem concerning a form :

I wish to have a webpage on which a teacher could edit the marks obtained by a student to his homeworks. Of course, I have `Student`, `Homework` and `Mark` entities. This last one is the owner of 2 `ManyToOne` relations with the two first entities.

The basic solution is to create a form for each homework. But on the long term, there will have too much forms on the same page. And by the way, it would be too boring to have to validate each form if he has to change a lot of values.

I think that I have to deal with a field with the type `collection` but I don't know how to exploit it :

- How can I get the homework list (in order to generate a corresponding `Mark` form) ? And where to implement this task?
- How to access to the homework entity's attributes from the view ? For example, to print the homework's dueDate.

Thank's a lot for your answers!

Comment: Collection is what you want but they cannot be explained in a few lines.  Work through and understand the example in the cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html